# Button appears when condition met

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm new to python, and i am trying out tkinter. Currently im using `random` to choose from a list. When the list is chosen, i want certain button to appear. Etc, when Pinoeer Mrt is choosen, Button1 appears for me to click, else if others are choosen, Same button appears but perform another function.

I have looked into stackoverflow for help, but cant seem to find any related to my needs. If u have any link, please comment below and i will take a look.Thanks!

```
def lunchLocation():

    location_list = ['Pinoeer Mrt', 'Joo Koon Mrt', 'Avenue 3 - Hot Sun', 'Walk 1km - Hot Sun']

    Location = random.choice(location_list)
    print("Today we eat at ",Location ," lah!")

def foodChoicePinoeer():

    ryan_Pinoeer = ['Minced Meat Noodle', 'Hotplate Chicken', 'fishball Soup']
    elieen_Pinoeer = ['Hotplate Chicken', 'fishballNoodle' , 'banMian']
    tommy_Pinoeer = ['Chicken Rice', 'Hotplate chicken', 'Chai Fan']
    rob_Pinoeer = ['Hotplate Chicken', 'Ban Mian', 'Minced Meat Noodle']

    ryan = random.choice(ryan_Pinoeer)
    print("Today Ryan eat ",ryan_Pinoeer, 'ok?')
    print("/nWhile Elieen eat ",elieen_Pinoeer,'lah !')
    print("/nAnd Tommy will eat ",tommy_Pinoeer,'!!')
    print("/nLastly rob will eat ",rob_Pinoeer," hor")

root = tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas1.pack()

button1 = tk.Button(text='Choose Food', command=foodChoicePinoeer(), bg='brown', fg='white')

canvas1.create_window(300, 150, window=button1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking - there is no method to "choose" in your current code. But for starters, you made a common mistake by passing `foodChoicePinoeer()` to the command. You need to pass a reference, which is `foodChoicePinoeer` without `()`.

Comment: Lets say `location` =  "Pinoeer Mrt" , Button1 is visible. if `location` = "Avenue 3", Button1 is invisible. Can i do that

Comment: I don't see why you can't do that. But currently you are not even executing the function `lunchLocation`.

Comment: Yes i know, i just want to know how can i do that. Once i know i will be proceeding to doing that function as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply move your `create_window` method inside your `lunchLocation` function. Add a `if` clause to check whether the location meets your requirement.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

def lunchLocation():

    location_list = ['Pinoeer Mrt', 'Joo Koon Mrt', 'Avenue 3 - Hot Sun', 'Walk 1km - Hot Sun']

    Location = random.choice(location_list)
    print (Location)
    if Location == 'Pinoeer Mrt':
        print("Today we eat at ",Location ," lah!")
        canvas1.create_window(300, 150, window=button1)

def foodChoicePinoeer():
    ...

root = tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas1.pack()

button1 = tk.Button(text='Choose Food', command=foodChoicePinoeer, bg='brown', fg='white')
lunchLocation()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: One more question, how can i call command as reference? Im new to python.

Comment: Pass the command as name only, without using parenthesis, like `command=foodChoicePinoeer` as shown above.